# How to use python scheduler library to run parallel tasks?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

What is the method to use python scheduler library to run parallel tasks with multi core cpu?

Any example to add timeout and some sequential dependent elements and exception handling in this parallel tasks example?

Comment: In what parallel tasks example?  Were you going to add some code?

Comment: I have no example code, but I guess the logic like getting stock quote, pre trade , trade , post trade , and update system non trade signal, there is timeout , retry, and sequential that must run before next job and parallel tasks etc

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not posted any code at all, its hard to figure what you are trying to ask and what exactly you want to implement.

That being said I guess if you want to achieve ***True*** parallelism in python the library you want to use should be `multiprocessing`. With `multiprocessing` you can launch independent python processes from your main process and have them run on different physical cores at the same time.

If the tasks are dependent on each other then you need to use Inter Process Communication techniques like `Queues`, `Pipes` or Shared IPC objects provided by `multiprocessing` library itself like `multiprocessing` `array`, `value`, `multiprocessing` `Manager`.

For independent tasks you won't have to worry much about syncing the process states, however if you need to combine the results of independent tasks you can use things like `multiprocessing` `pool` and `map`.

However if all you intend to do is to execute tasks concurrently and thereby do not want to waste any CPU time, you can look at `threading` library albeit, `threading`, has its own complications, `GIL` being the biggest one.

`async` is another paradigm that you want to look at which takes altogether different approache to concurrency, but `async` has its own ecosystem and everything need to part of this ecosystem to actually achieve the desired end result otherwise the whole thing blows out.

Comment: I find https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-to-execute-jobs-in-parallel    , can you scheduler directly instead of low level programming ? Because I think that if user space had already had scheduler library , why not directly use this ?

Comment: Is there parallel scheduler?

Comment: I haven't explored `schedule` but as mentioned in my answer if you actually want to spawn tasks that run parallel you would have to use `multiprocessing`. Also as for scheduling tasks i would much rather prefer `kernel` and python handle that for me rather than me messing with kernel scheduling. Also from first glance it looks like `schedule` is a pythonic implementation to what we have `cron` in linux, even in the link you posted the example is using `threading` to spawn tasks. Threads in python do not give parallelism although you can achieve concurrency for IO bound tasks with threads.